# Stepwise function in gnuplot

Tags: gnuplot

I want to know how to create the plot of a stepwise function in Gnuplot. The function I want to plot includes the operations cost for several distance range and multiple products. For instance, if the distance is 0-300 Km for product 1 the cost is 1.05 $/Km and for product 2, it is 0.86 $/Km. When the distance increases, the cost for each product decrease.

I have defined one function for each product and plot them functions together:

```
gnuplot> f(x)=x<=300 ? 1.05 : x<=650 ? 0.65 : x<=1300 ? 0.46 : x<=1950 ? 0.4 : x<=3250 ? 0.31 : 0.22

gnuplot> x<=300 ? 0.86 : x<=650 ? 0.53 : x<=1300 ? 0.38: x<=1950 ? 0.32 : x<=3250 ? 0.24 : 0.19

gnuplot> plot [0:5000][0:3] f(x), g(x)
```

There is one problem: I can not remove the vertical lines. Any idea?

Thanks for your help

[image]

Comment: Seems like I am not allowed to add picture in my post. I hope that my question is stilll enough clear without the image.

Comment: I added the image for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are basically two approaches you can take.  The best approach is to use a datafile, but you can use functions, although it will be more difficult.

### Datafile Approach

You are probably going to have trouble doing this as a function, because you are going to get those vertical lines.  A datafile gives you a little better control, and even allows you to mark the end points of the pieces of the piecewise function with the typical open/closed dots.  Set up your data file with this format:

```
x y # left point of piece 1
x y # right point of piece 1
    # one single blank line
x y # left point of piece 2
x y # right point of piece 2
    # one single blank line
...
```

With your function f, we can do this like

```
0 1.05
300 1.05

300 0.65
650 0.65

650 0.46
1300 0.46

1300 0.4
1950 0.4

1950 0.31
3250 0.31

3250 0.22
6000 0.22
```

then `plot datafile with lines` gives

[image]

We can get even fancier with<sup>**†**</sup>

```
plot datafile w lines,\
     last=0,\
     "" u 1:(oldlast=last,last=$1,$1==oldlast?$2:1/0) w points pt 6 lt 1,\
     last=0,\         
     "" u 1:(oldlast=last,last=$1,$1==oldlast?1/0:$2) w points pt 7 lt 1
```

to produce

[image]

Here we first plot the same curve as before.  Then we initialize the variable *last* to be 0 (the value of the first x coordinate)<sup>**‡**</sup>, and plot the open dots.

To do this we evaluate `(oldlast=last,last=$1,$1==oldlast?$2:1/0)` which first stores the value of last as *oldlast* and then stores the value of the first column (the x coordinate) as *last* to use on the next point.  Finally we check to see if the x-coordinate is the same as the value of *oldlast* (the value of the x-coordinate from the last point).  If it is, we use the 2nd column value, otherwise we use the unplottable `1/0`.  This will cause points to be plotted only if the are the first point in the two point blocks.  We plot these with points using pointstyle 6 (an open point) and linetype 1 (the same as used in the lines).

We do the same thing again, but this time plot the second points with filled dots (pointtype 7).

We can either add the points for the function g to the same file, separating it from the others by two blank lines and then use indexes to refer to them, or create a separate datafile for g.  We can then add similar plot commands to the current command.  For example, if we use the same file with function f followed by function g, we can do:

```
plot datafile i 0 w lines,\
     last=0,\
     "" i 0 u 1:(oldlast=last,last=$1,$1==oldlast?$2:1/0) w points pt 6 lt 1,\
     last=0,\         
     "" i 0 u 1:(oldlast=last,last=$1,$1==oldlast?1/0:$2) w points pt 7 lt 1,\
     datafile i 1 w lines,\
     last=0,\
     "" i 1 u 1:(oldlast=last,last=$1,$1==oldlast?$2:1/0) w points pt 6 lt 1,\
     last=0,\         
     "" i 1 u 1:(oldlast=last,last=$1,$1==oldlast?1/0:$2) w points pt 7 lt 1
```

### Function Approach

As far as getting only one jump, your functions have a lot of redundant conditions.  Redefine f (and similarly for g) as

```
f(x)=x<=300 ? 1.05 : x<=650 ? 0.65 : x<=1300 ? 0.46 : x<=1950 ? 0.4 : x<=3250 ? 0.31 : 0.22
```

and then plot it.  Make sure that the samples are set high enough, otherwise you may end up collecting multiple jumps together or get undesirable slanted lines.  With

```
set xrange[0:6000]
set yrange[0:2]
set samples 1000
plot f(x)
```

we get

[image]

However, this will still get the vertical connecting lines.  This is going to be very hard to avoid with a function.  The best way that I can think of to avoid this is to inject a very small non-plottable value just before the breaks.  For f(x), we can do this with

```
f(x)=x<=290 ? 1.05 : x<=300? (1/0) : x<=640? 0.65 : x<=650 ? (1/0) : x<=1290 ? 0.46 : x<=1300 ? (1/0) : x<=1940? 0.4 : x<=1950 ? (1/0) : x<=3240 ? 0.31: x<=3250? (1/0) : 0.22
```

Here, we have inject a non-plottable value of `1/0` for a region of length 10 just before the breaks.  Smaller lengths can be used as well.  If we set the samples high enough to be sure that the sampling hits each of these breaks (in this case a sample of 1000 like before is good enough), it will avoid connecting the points.

[image]

With samples set too small (for example 100), we might still get the connecting lines

[image]

Thus if we use a gap with a size smaller than 10, we may need to use higher sampling to avoid the connecting lines.  Larger gaps may work with smaller sampling.

Depending on the sampling, the gaps might be larger than specified as well if the sampling is too low.  For example, setting the gaps to a size of 100 with

```
f(x)=x<=200 ? 1.05 : x<=300? (1/0) : x<=550? 0.65 : x<=650 ? (1/0) : x<=1200 ? 0.46 : x<=1300 ? (1/0) : x<=1850? 0.4 : x<=1950 ? (1/0) : x<=3150 ? 0.31: x<=3250? (1/0) : 0.22
```

and a sampling of 10, we get

[image]

where the gaps have a size of 222.22 (I have added labels to make it easy to compute the gap size<sup>**Δ**</sup>), but with a sampling of 1000, we get

[image]

where the gaps have size 101.1, very close to the value of 100 specified in the function.

To use functions to do this, therefore, use this model and set the gap size to a value small enough that it will appear non-existent on the final graph (notice that on the graph from 0 to 6000, we can barely see the gap size of 10), and then set the samples reasonably high.

With the function approach, I don't know of any way to add the filled and open dots if those are desired.

---

<sup>**†**</sup> Gnuplot version 5.1 (the current development version) supports a `pointtype variable` option which can simplify this to

```
plot last=0,\
     datafile u 1:2:(oldlast=last,last=$1,$1==oldlast?6:7) w linespoints pt var lt 1
```

Here we just plot all points, but use the same test as before to select between pointtype 7 or 6.  As we can do both point types at once, we can just use the linespoints style instead of doing two separate plots.

<sup>**‡**</sup> Initializing last to a value less than the first x-coordinate will cause that first point to be filled.

<sup>**Δ**</sup> To draw these labels, in the first case (with `set xrange[0:1000]` and `set samples 10`), I used

```
plot f(x),\
     "+" u 1:(f($1)+0.1):(abs($1-250)<150||abs($1-600)<160?sprintf("%0.2f",$1):"") w labels
```

and in the case of `set samples 1000`

```
plot f(x),\
     "+" u 1:(f($1)+0.1):(abs($1-250)<51||abs($1-600)<51?sprintf("%0.2f",$1):"") w labels
```

It takes a little playing around with the bounds on the `abs` functions here to get the desired labels to appear.  Examining the output using `set table` can be helpful for getting them right.

Comment: It worked very well with data file. Thanks. 
A quick question: is there a way to specify the path to the folder in which I am keeping the data file, once and they just referring to data file by its name (like stepwise.txt) instead of the entire path?

Comment: @Helia You could store the path to the file in a variable and then just use that variable instead of specifying the file path.  For example `datafile = "path/to/file.txt"` (or `datafile = "c:\\path\\to\\file.txt"` on Windows) and then just use the variable **datafile** in your plot command like `plot datafile u 1:2`.

Comment: My only issue now is when plotting more than one datafile (one for each product).
Some lines of a new step, start very close to the end of lines belonging to the previous step. They even overlap at some points.

Comment: @Helia Without knowing what your data looks like and exactly the commands you are running, I can't say much about that.  If they are close to the same values, they should start close to the same lines.  If they have the same values, they will overlap.  What do you expect to happen?  Why is this incorrect behavior?  Can you tell me what the data looks like and the commands you are using?

Comment: I could fix the problem with crowded plot by changing the distance intervals. Before, the first interval was 0-300 and the next interval was started on 301. Thus, the lines would be very close on the plot. When adding the same function for several products, the plot got really crowded. So, I just start the next distance interval with 5 units gap. Thanks

Answer (score -1):

Your ternary statements are trying to do too much.  When you are writing

```
f0(x)=(x_low < x <= x_high) ? y : 0
```

you should be writing

```
f0(x)=((x_low < x) && ( x <= x_high)) ? y : 0
```

So your function `f(x)` should look like

```
f(x)=(x<=300) ? 1.05 : (x<=650) ? 0.65 : (x<=1300) ? 0.46 : (x<=1950) ? 0.4 : (x<=3250) ? 0.31 : (x<3250) ? 0.22 : 0
```

---

As for the plotting style if you want it to be discontinuous, use separate functions for the steps like and plot them individually. Your first function would be split up like:

```
f1(x)=           (x<=300) ? 1.05 : 1/0
f2(x)=(x>300) && (x<=650) ? 0.65 : 1/0
...
```

If you just want steps without interpolation, use steps

```
plot [0:6000][0:3] f(x) w steps, g(x) w steps
```